# Нумерация изображений и других объектов по главам, ("Рисунок 1.1" в главе 1, "Рисунок 2.1" в главе 2) в LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libre-office

Оформляю диплом. Есть требование к нумерации рисунков как указано в заголовке вопроса. Пример:

> ### Глава 1
>
> Бла-бла-бла на рисунке 1.1
> [рисунок]
> *Рисунок 1.1: Бла-бла-бла*
>
> Бла-бла-бла на рисунке 1.2
> [рисунок]
> *Рисунок 1.2: Бла-бла-бла*
>
> ### Глава 2
>
> Бла-бла-бла на рисунке 2.1
> [рисунок]
> *Рисунок 2.1: Бла-бла-бла*

Сейчас у меня нумерация рисунков сквозная по всему документу, то есть подписи просто "Рисунок 1", "Рисунок 2" и т.д.
В тексте ссылки на рисунки тоже хочется автоматические, а не писать руками.
Как добиться форматирования как в примере?

*P.S. Знаю что вопрос не совсем по теме этого сайта. Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет куда правильнее обратиться.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не сложно. Вставляете рисунок, щёлкаете правой кнопкой и выбираете из меню "Вставить название" (обычно это предпоследний пункт контекстного меню). Или выбираете пункт [**Название**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/ru/text/swriter/01/04060000.html) из меню Вставка (активируется, если выделен графический объект, в т.ч. рисунок)

[image: Выбор пункта Название из меню]

В следующем окне укажите Категорию Рисунок и с помощью кнопки [**Параметры**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/ru/text/swriter/01/04060100.html) укажите, что номер главы нужен в нумерации
[image: Категория и Параметры]

Comment: Спасибо, просто супер!